# Is there a way to do PATCH request with Marketing Cloud AmpScript or SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, httprequest, ssjs, patch

In Marketing Cloud AmpScript and SSJS, there is are no references for PATCH request. I wonder if we are able to make PATCH request? I'm trying to update a mobile connect record and I'm able to do so with Postman, CUrl or Ajax. However, I would like to try doing within a cloudpage using PATCH request!

Any alternative way to do PATCH request? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who stumbles upon this:

Yes, see this post; [REST API Methods in AMPScript or SSJS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204006/rest-api-methods-in-ampscript-or-ssjs?rq=1)