# SFMC outbound API calls

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

Can SFMC make outbound API calls to an external web service?

I'm trying to find a solution on the web but it doesn't seem to be anything related to this out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can!

There are two 'default' options via [GET](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httpget.htm) and [POST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httppost.htm) (and [POST2](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httppost2.htm)) functions. There are also [SSJS versions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_httpFunctions.htm) of these functions as well.

But there is also another [Script.Util.HttpRequest()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationScriptUtilHttpRequest.htm) option for any of the different methods you may want outside POST and GET.

Full details on script.util [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204006/rest-api-methods-in-ampscript-or-ssjs/204497#204497) from my previous answer/investigation on it.

HTTPGET example:
`HTTPGet('http://www.example.com',false,0,@CallStatus)`

HTTPPost example:
`%%=HTTPPost("http://example.com","text/html",@exampleContent,@CallStatus)=%%`

HTTPPost2 example:

```
%%[var @output,@respheader]%%
%%=HTTPPost2('http://www.example.com/','text/html', '', true, @output,@respheader, 'Authorization', 'Example', 'User-Agent', 'Example')=%%
Output: %%=v(@output)=%%
Header: %%=v(@respheader)=%%
```

Sample of Script.Util.HttpRequest: 
*(this one is internal facing, but can be used for external endpoints as well)*

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var accessToken = {{yourToken}};
var url = 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/{{ContentID}}'

var payload = '{{yourPayload}}';

var auth = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;

  var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
  req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
  req.retries = 2;
  req.continueOnError = true;
  req.contentType = "application/json"
  req.setHeader("Authorization", auth);
  req.method = "PUT"; /*** You can change the method here ***/
  req.postData = payload;

  var resp = req.send();
</script>
```

Comment: How to send certificate and key file in this request?