# Details for function Script.Util.HttpRequest

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, api

Can someone give me more details of the function `Script.Util.HttpRequest` mentioned on the site:

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationScriptUtilHttpRequest.htm

Beyond the example, are there more methods available? And are there descriptions for the methods, for example for `req.emptyContentHandling`?

Answer (score 7):

I acutally just wrote an [article on this](https://gortonington.com/restapimethodinssjs/) in my brand spanking new blog.  Below are the highlights from it as well as a sample taken from my original SFSE post on it.

Here are the available Methods:

```
GET
DELETE
HEAD
OPTIONS
PATCH
POST
PUT
```

Here is a working sample (taken from [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/204006/12730))

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var accessToken = {{yourToken}};
var url = 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/{{ContentID}}'

var payload = '{{yourPayload}}';

var auth = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;

  var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
  req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
  req.retries = 2;
  req.continueOnError = true;
  req.contentType = "application/json"
  req.setHeader("Authorization", auth);
  req.method = "PUT"; /*** You can change the method here ***/
  req.postData = payload;

  var resp = req.send();
</script>
```

and below is an overview on the above code:

> **auth** is the authorization token (in this sample, the OAuth token you get via API for SFMC.) The assumption being that you have already
>   made the call to the auth URL to receive the token. Its value is the
>   combination of the accessToken (OAuth) and the require prepend of
>   ‘Bearer ‘.
>
> **url** is the complete url of your API call. This includes the base url, the endpoint and any ‘unique ids’ necessary (e.g. {{ConntentID}}
>   in the sample)
>
> **payload** this is the xml/json/etc. ‘body’ of your request. If you are doing POST, PUT, PATCH, etc. This is basically the part that tells
>   the endpoint what to do to what. As it varies depending on endpoint
>   and system, I left this as just a variable in the sample.
>
> **req** is very similar to WSProxy and is setting up the Request as an object for us to enter information into.
>
> **req.emptyContentHandling** is actually pretty self explanatory, value of ‘true’ (1) will let the call continue without error if the
>   payload is empty. ‘False’ (0) will cause an error if the payload is
>   empty.
>
> **req.retries** sets the amount of retry attempts the function will do before failing the call.
>
> **req.continueOnError** is pretty self explanatory as well. If you have true, it will continue the request regardless of non-fatal
>   errors. On false, it will fail the call if there are any non-fatal
>   errors.
>
> **req.contentType** is the definition of the content type of the payload.
>
> **req.setHeader** sets the name/value pairs inside of the header of the API call. In my sample, I included the Authorization header values
>
> **req.method** is where you would select the method of your call. e.g. PUT, POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, etc.
>
> **req.postData** is where the payload we previously created is stored.
>
> **req.Send()** is then the execution of the fully formed call after all the pieces have been put together.