# Sending SMS after subscribing through Landing Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, cloudpage, marketingcloudapi

I am trying to build a functionality where I want to send SMS immediately when a contact fills in the details in cloud page form.
This cloud page saves those records in a Data Extension. I am not sure how should be the flow of this process.

1. Am I supposed to use API Event to achieve this?
2. How could the new mobile numbers be subscribed to certain keyword?
3. Is it ok if those numbers are not present in All Contacts?

I've read using 'QueueMO REST API trigger' this can be done, but I have never done this before. 
Would be a great help, if someone could guide through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to trigger an SMS and use a data extension and don't want to use the Smart Capture approach as described by fromero, you need to use the REST API. You can do this with use of QueueMO method you're referring to: [QueueMO REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postQueueMO.htm). This can be done with HTTP request SSJS function, see this post for further information: [REST API Methods in AMPScript or SSJS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204006/rest-api-methods-in-ampscript-or-ssjs).
2. You define the keyword in the QueueMO REST call.
3. The numbers will be added to All Contacts if not existing. You can also add a SubscriberKey.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Journey using the CloudPage as entry source. Then, when someone submits it, will be automatically injected in the journey where the SMS is sent. Just remind to add that field in the Data Extension.