# Parse JSON array of ids into payload using ssjs

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, ssjs

I need to create a json payload to send data in this format

```js
{
   "ids":[
      "6375502",
       "637550",
      "6376391"
   ],
   "type":"MrnId",
   "extId":"104DC758-25AE-47A8-931A-DD9DC1637049"
}
```

How should I write the payload?
One sample is below -

```js
var payload = '{"ids":arr,"type":"MrnId",
   "extId":"104DC758-25AE-47A8-931A-DD9DC1637049"}';
```

here `arr` is the array of ids

Comment: I'm writing the code in ssjs for an HTTP post request. Any ssjs resources will be really helpful.

Comment: There are a number of Q&As here on SSJS and JSON, here's [one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204006/rest-api-methods-in-ampscript-or-ssjs). Please do a search.