HTTP DELETE for a Push Location
I'm trying to delete a Location through rest api with the api documented here.
The script I'm using is:
*code to get the authentication*

var IdLocationsDelete = ["ID1", "ID2"]
var delLocation = IdLocationsDelete[k];
var url_delete = baseUrl + '/push/v1/location/' + delLocation;
            
var deleteResponse = HTTP.Delete(url_delete, headerNames, headerValues);

if (deleteResponse.StatusCode == 200) {
    Write("Location '" + delLocation + "' deleted successfully.<br>");
} else {
    Write("Failed to delete location '" + delLocation + "' - Status code: " + deleteResponse.StatusCode + ", Response: " + deleteResponse.Response[0] + "<br>");
}

But HTTP.Delete method is not being recognized as expected. I'm testing it in a landing page and when trying to publish I receive the following error:
" Error Message: "Object expected: Delete"
Description: "Jint.Native.JsException: Object expected: Delete Exception of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown. - from Jint " "
How can I make the api call to delete the locations by id?

There's no HTTP.Delete but you can use another script object. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204006/rest-api-methods-in-ampscript-or-ssjs

As @identigral commented above, you can use the Script.Util.HttpRequest() function as it lets you be more flexible with the method.
You can alter the your code something like this:
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");


var accessToken = "YOUR ACCESS TOKEN";
var baseUrl = 'https://domain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com';

var IdLocationsDelete = ["ID1", "ID2"]
var delLocation = IdLocationsDelete[k];

var url_delete = baseUrl + '/push/v1/location/' + delLocation;

var auth = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;

  var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url_delete);
  req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
  req.retries = 2;
  req.continueOnError = true;
  req.contentType = "application/json"
  req.setHeader("Authorization", auth);
  req.method = "DELETE"; /*** You can change the method here ***/

  var resp = req.send();
  
Write(Stringify(resp.statusCode)); // success status would be 200
</script>

